# Check if ImageSource is empty

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone

I'm using `Binding` to `Image.SourceProperty` from `byte[]` variable. At `IValueConverter` I check if `value.Length > 0`, if yes then I set source from it's value. Then I need to know, if it was set, so I can show or hide clear button. `Image.Source` always is not null. How can know, if it was set from `byte[]` array?
My code:

```
var bnd = new Binding
{
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    Path = new PropertyPath("DataPath.Value"),
    Converter = new ByteToImageConverter()
};
myImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, bnd);

public class ByteToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = value as byte[];
        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
        if (val.Length > 0) {
            bmp.SetSource(new MemoryStream(val));
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(value as BitmapSource);
        bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 150, 200, 0, 100);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Now I need code to check, if image source property is set:

```
// myImage.Source always != null even if there was no bmp.SetSource() call
var str = myImage.Source != null ? "Image is set" : "Image is empty";
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I am not sure I understand what your scenario is?

Answer (score 0):

something like that

```
if (((BitmapImage)myImage.Source).UriSource == null)
{
 //Image is empty
}
```

or

```
var str = ((BitmapImage)myImage.Source).UriSource != null ? "Image is set" : "Image is empty";
```